# Size attribute not visible for configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, theme, frontend, custom-attributes

I have a magento site with clothing apparels as products. I felt the need to revamp the website and so I am in the process of changing the website's theme. Everything worked perfect until I tested the product view page. There, for the earlier theme, the page looked like this (see the size select dropdown)

[image]

After applying the new theme, the page looks like this below image (the size dropdown is nowhere to be seen). I am unable to find out where I am going wrong. Some tutorials suggested to edit the **catalog.xml** file for the theme, but since I am a newbie and the tutorial doesn't had enough explanation for someone like me, I refrained from going ahead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the Display Product Options value in the Design product tab:

[image]

Flush the cache and check if it resolved your problem.